# Set default value to react boostrap Form.Check

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have the following code for the checkbox:

```
<Form.Group  controlId="formBasicCheckbox">
       <Form.Check
             onChange={(disabled)=> {disabled ? packed = 'yes' : packed = 'no'}} >
       </Form.Check>
</Form.Group>
```

Also I need to set default value to it but can't find a way to do that. I tried 'value', 'defaultValue', but nothing helps and google neither.

Comment: Have you tried `checked`?

Comment: @rfestag doesn't work also

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`defaultValue` does work but take note that this is primarily for uncontrolled components. Since you have an `onChange` I think what you want is `value` instead (unless the `onChange` is to for another purpose - regardless I have code below that can help).

If it helps you can also use `defaultChecked` prop which accepts a boolean that will set if the checkbox should initially be checked or not (you can also use `checked` prop - but at that point you need to control its value via, for example, state).

In addition, I think you are misunderstanding the `onChange` prop. Its callback argument is a SyntheticEvent - I find that `disabled` is an odd identifier for that and confusing. See code below for insight

```
const [packed, setPacked] = React.useState("yes");

<Form.Check
  defaultChecked={true} // if checkbox should be checked by default
  // defaultValue="yes" // use this instead of value if you want uncontrolled component
  value={packed} // state-controlled value of checkbox
  onChange={(e) => {
    // e.target.checked will return true or false if checkbox is checked
    e.target.checked ? setPacked("yes") : setPacked("no");
  }}
></Form.Check>
```

[image: Edit pedantic-cori-cf2ed]

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else who read this and couldn't get the Form.Check to set its value correctly, the property to use it seems is checked - not value. (when using state-controlled value of checkbox)

Answer (score 1):

As renrutsirhcs said,the correct property is "checked".There is no documentation about this propery on react-bootstrap docs but it works which is weird.

Comment: please comment renrutsirhcs answer instead and delete this one