React Bootstrap Radion Buttons how to set default value
I am getting values of radio buttons from array and listing these options.
When I map all elements of array, by default none of the options is selected.
I tried to set first option with "checked" and "defaultChecked" but not worked. When I use "checked" my function is not working anymore.
How can I set first option by default here?
const genders = [
  {
    id: 1,
    gender: "male",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    gender: "female",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    gender: "do not want to share",
  },
];

export function Gender() {
  const [genderValue, setGender] = useState(1);

  const changeGenderValue = (e) => {
    const genderInputValue = e.target.id;
    setGender(genderInputValue);
    console.log(genderInputValue);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Form>
        {genders.map((gender, key) => (
          <Form.Check
            key={key}
            className="mb-3"
            label={gender.gender}
            name="gendersInput"
            type="radio"
            id={gender.id}
            value={genderValue}
            onChange={changeGenderValue}
          />
        ))}
      </Form>
    </>
  );
}


Is this what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/a/63942730/8681416

conditionally setting defaultChecked was solution in my case.
I solved my issue with the code below.
<Form>
            {productStatusTypes.map((type, key) => (
              <Form.Check
                key={key}
                className="mb-3"
                type="radio"
                id={type.id}
                label={type.name}
                name="productStatus"
                value={filteredShop}
                onChange={onProductStatusChange}
                defaultChecked={type.id == 1}
              />
            ))}
          </Form>

